How to get the caret distance from the left inside an input field?
I want to know the caret distance from the left in side an input field. How can I achieve this ?
I know that inputEl.selectionStart will give me the position of the caret but how can I determine the distance from the left ?

Do you mean like how many pixels?

@DanielA.White Yes

@fdomn-m yes, only close logic that i got was to create a faux element and put the characters before the the current caret position and then find the outerwidth of the faux element, but this would break the logic if i have too much text inside the input field and some text is hidden in the overflow of the input field.
